# Quando e como utilizar o asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Venho estudando Asp.net MVC a algum tempo, tenho lido sobre `WebApi` mas ainda não consegui entender quando e como posso utiliza-lo.

Ex: Tenho um pequeno sistema de notícias, onde tenho uma `area` onde fica a parte administrativa e no projeto raiz o site em si.

Como eu poderia utilizar o `WebApi` neste cenário ou em que cenário e mais propício o seu uso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo tanta usabilidade para este cenário que você citou, mas sim é possível utilizar.

Se sua aplicação é uma SPA (Single Page Applications), ou seja, que possua apenas uma página, sim ela deve utilizar WebApi, pois é comum nesta aplicação a utilização de Ajax na qual você irá retornar para o cliente apenas o que for necessário, em outras palavras, a informação já é tratada e irei apenas mostrar para o usuário aquilo que ele solicitou.

Neste tipo de aplicação o consumo de dados deve ser menor, que também pode ser aplicado para serviços que serão disponibilizados para dispositivos mobile.

Voltando ao seu cenário com o modulo administrativo, você pode sim fazer a publicação da noticia via `Ajax`, e no caso usaria `POST` e o retorno poderia ser um *boolean* indicando: Sim a matéria foi publicada (*True*); Não foi possivel publicar a matéria (*False*); neste caso você receberia o dado, trataria no seu javascript e mostraria de forma amigável ao usuário, tudo isso sem atualizar a página. As possibilidades seriam infinitas, isso depende do seu conhecimento.

Eu utilizo WebApi para retorno de dados em Json e até mesmo o HTML pronto, eu diminuo e muito a carga de dados.

Falei pouco e você pode não ter entendido ainda a real usabilidade, então vamos lá.

Imagine o seguinte cenário, possuo um site que disponibiliza uma Api para você recuperar informações de bandas. Funcionaria da seguinte forma, o usuário me envia o artista/banda e eu retorno para ele em json/xml informações sobre o artista.

Controller

```
public class ArtistaController : ApiController {
    public Artista Get(string artista) {
       Artista artista = new Artista();      
       .... minha lógica, com modelos etc...
       return artista;
    }
}
```

A Url de requisição (GET) seria: `http://meuexemplo.com/Api/Artista/Nome_do_Artista`

E suponhamos que eu tenha o modelo pronto do objeto Artista, esse seria o retorno em `json`

Minha Url de requisição para a banda Alexisonfire `http://meuexemplo.com/Api/Artista/Alexisonfire`

Retorno

> [{"Artist" : "Alexisonfire", "Genre" : "Post Hardcore"}]

E por final quem solicitou pode adaptar as informações à aplicação dele.

***Dicas complementares***

Retornar *HTML* no Controller sem WebAPi

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ActionName("Index")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PartialIndex()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Note que estou usando o `[HttpPost]`, isso quer dizer que toda vez que eu enviar um Post ele irá me retornar a `View Partial` e não a View inteira.

Espero que tenha compreendido.

Comment: Tenho usado web api com WCF em arquitetura REST. Alguém me disse ser esse uma forma ideal do uso do web api.

Comment: @diego-vieira Como disse estudo MVC a pouco tempo e realmente ainda não tenho muito conhecimento, quero deixar minhas aplicações mais dinâmicas e amigáveis, por exemplo: O meu painel administrativo a cada ação dá refresh na página toda e estou procurando a melhor maneira de deixar tudo mais dinâmico e sem tanto refresh, achei que o wepapi poderia me ajudar.

Comment: @HermesAutran, Então, pode usar sem medo, o caminho é usar WebApi mesmo se você quer remover o refresh do seu sistema, se quiser posso dar uma complementada ai na resposta com mais situações com seu caso de uso, ok?

Comment: @diego-vieira Se puder complementar algo mais seria muito bom, se tiver alguma sugestão de outro modo que resultaria no mesmo resultado que eu quero será bem vinda!

Comment: @HermesAutran, tem uma aplicação que estou fazendo no trabalho e para html eu faço no controller normal mesmo, tem um truque pra você em vez de retornar a View você retorna a partial view, quando são dados (Objetos, Modelos, listas, etc..) eu utilizo WebApi.

Comment: @DiegoVieira Tens algum artigo ou tutorial onde possa ler e estudar sobre esse procedimento ou foi você quem criou? Se foi você, pode compartilhar?

Comment: @HermesAutran vou colocar na resposta como exemplo se não fico sujo aqui nos comentários